# Write a parity class. The class supplies a member function named put, which counts the number of elements supplied.

Tags: c++, class

I'm completing an O'reilly textbook on my own and I am now on classes.
Here is the programming exercise copied word for word:

"Exercise 13-1: Write a parity class. The class supplies a member function named put, which counts the number of elements supplied. The other member function test returns true if an even number of put calls have been made and false otherwise.
Member functions:
`void parity::put( );` // Count another element
`bool parity::test( );` // Return `true` if an even number of puts have been done. Return `false` for an odd number."

I believe I have the right idea for my program. I completed it and it has no errors but it does not work properly and has a break point. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
class parity {

    private:
        int count; //number of puts done.

    public:
        void init();//initialize the put
        void put(const int item); //count another element
        bool test( ); //return true of even number of puts have been done. Return false for an odd number
};

inline void parity::init()
{
    count = 0;
}

inline void parity::put(const int item)
{
    count = item;
    ++count;
}

inline bool parity::test()
{
    if (count % 2 == 0)
    {
        return true;
        std::cout << "Amount of puts is even";
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
        std::cout << "Amount of puts is not even";
    }
}

int main ()
{
    parity a_parity;

    a_parity.init();

    a_parity.put(1);
    a_parity.put(2);
    a_parity.put(3);

    a_parity.test();

    return 0;
}
```

I believe the error is in my `parity::put` member function but I dont know. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maurice; Please try to be a bit less abrasive to people trying to help you ask better questions, so you can get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `count = item;` is the problem.

```
inline void parity::put(const int item)
{
    // count = item; 
    ++count;
}
```

should work, as you do not reset the value of `count` every time you call `put`.

Comment: well now it works w/o any breakpoints but it's still not outputting anything at all. Just running with no errors and also doing nothing.

Comment: @MauriceAbney Yes. Your `test()` function generates output _after_ `return`.

Comment: That solved my problem :) I had no idea I had to generate output before returning anything. I learn something new every day. Thanks man.